# importing turtle module in VS Code gives ModuleNotFoundError: 'tkinter'

Tags: python, visual-studio, tkinter, python-turtle, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import turtle module. but it shows me module name 'tkinter' is not found. although it is a built-in module.and i didnt import it directly.(i think turtle module imports tkinter for me.)

I tried changing the path for Python in VS Code by clicking the bottom left option is status bar.

other modules are getting imported(import random, etc)

I have attached the screenshot of the code and error i am getting.
Please HELPPP!!!!

[image: The Code I am trying to run]

[image: The Error I am getting]

Comment: Install `tkinter`. You can `pip` install it.

Comment: tkinter cannot be installed by pip.

Comment: Try installing something like `python3-tk` package by the OS package manager.

Comment: It did not work, shows the following error..:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

i have been trying since 3 days.
Please do somthing someone.

Comment: @acw1668 by os package manager you mean the app shop right? (i am new to linux too)

Comment: You should read the document for your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be an import error that you facing with you IDE (VS Code). Try changing the target exe to the python interpreter in your virtual environment. You can learn more about this, by visiting the link below:

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/import-errors-in-python-no-module-named-module-name-for-vs-code-887d1f78cf02